# 'mod_rewrite' and pretty URLs with PHP

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get pretty URLs with PHP/.htaccess, but I get 500 server errors and cannot find what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the .htaccess file I use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /bulkmailer/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ /bulkmailer/index.php?prefix=$1&controller=$2&action=$3 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*) /bulkmailer/index.php?prefix=$1&controller=$2&action=$3 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/ /bulkmailer/index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) /bulkmailer/index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/ /bulkmailer/index.php?controller=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /bulkmailer/index.php?controller=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

An error log I can find:

```
[Wed Mar 20 23:44:30.232417 2013] [core:error] [pid 5432:tid 1656] [client ::1:4653] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Wed Mar 20 23:44:34.601496 2013] [core:error] [pid 5432:tid 1660] [client ::1:4654] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Wed Mar 20 23:44:34.601496 2013] [core:error] [pid 5432:tid 1660] [client ::1:4654] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you post your error_log ? `/path/to/apache/logs/error_log`

Comment: @AlexGittemeier added it in description

Comment: or you could write a router at the script level or use a framework , what you are doing is ugly and wont scale. it's 2013, a simple FallbackResource and a router script should be a reflex.

Comment: To go with mpm, you could take a look at the [klein router](https://github.com/chriso/klein.php) then you can do `RewriteRule . /bulkmailer/index.php`